# Read users and passwords from a txt file

Tags: php, file, file-io

I have a txt file which looks like this

> USER: user46226234
> PASS: #)(HF(WE*FHWE
>
> USER: user49503420594
> PASS: yellowbird
>
> USER: user449202934
> PASS: dog

I'm trying to extract each of these pairs and use them in a script.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your password file contains valid lines and empty lines only

```
$lines = file('file.txt');
$credentials = array();

foreach($lines as $line) {
    if(empty($line)) continue;

    // whole line
    $line = trim(str_replace(": ", ':', $line));
    $lineArr = explode(' ', $line);

    // username only
    $username = explode(':', $lineArr[0]);
    $username = array_pop($username);

    // password
    $password = explode(':', $lineArr[1]);
    $password = array_pop($password);

    // putting them together
    $credentials[$username] = $password;
}

print_r($credentials);
```

Comment: It seems to be working but I get errors: Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference and Notice: Undefined offset: 1. Also, with this way are the user and password paired and how can output their values? I'm sorry for asking so much questions, I just want to get work done and I'm not a programmer.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try `file_get_contents()` see it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

In case you want to use config files such .ini files you want to also check `parse_ini_files()` check it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php)